# React-router: IndexRoute vs DefaultRoute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm wondering what's the difference between `IndexRoute` and `DefaultRoute` in example below? As I understand in both cases `Home` will be rendered, right?

```
<Route path="/" handler={App}>
  <IndexRoute handler={Home}/>
  <Route path="about" handler={About}/>
</Route>
```

and

```
<Route path="/" handler={App}>
  <DefaultRoute handler={Home}/>
  <Route path="about" handler={About}/>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DefaultRoute` is gone as of react-router v1.0. `IndexRoute` is introduced  instead.

From the docs:

```
// v0.13.x
// with this route config
<Route path="/" handler={App}>
  <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={Home}/>
  <Route name="about" handler={About}/>
</Route>

// v1.0
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route path="about" component={About}/>
</Route>
```

More in the [upgrade guide.](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/febab4e1052d91df20944ffdf09a36a89a5b1f5c/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md)